# Reduce size of JSON object by skipping NULL properties

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

The JSON object returned by an AJAX call could have multiple properties with NULL values:

```
{
 Id: 1,
 Prop1: null,
 Prop2: null,
 Prop3: "abc"
}
```

Is there a way to tell MVC to skip the null values in the return object? Such trimmed down version of the JSON object would reduce payload by a lot.

```
{
 Id: 1,
 Prop3: "abc"
}
```

Does anyone have any idea about this approach?

Comment: Can you tell us how you are creating your Json at the moment?

Comment: I use [Controller.Json Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove null properties of a object sent to Json MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974811/remove-null-properties-of-a-object-sent-to-json-mvc)

Comment: Your referenced question is perfect. Please mark this question as duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to do that on my own, need more people to mark it as closed or someone with The Power©

Comment: I would recommend you don't do this because your code that needs to consume your JSON result would then need to check for a property existing on an object every time before attempting to use the value because you wont know which properties are `null` at a given time and that code would expect certain properties such as `Id` to work properly. If you know certain properties are null in specific situations maybe you can change your code prior to this to return different JSON results.

Comment: I know that Javascript use `Properties Bag`, and I understand the memory allocation difference between an undefined and a null valued properties. Indeed my js script has always check for falsy values before each use `if (x && x.y) { x.y.z(); }`. Does this mean there is no more risk?