# SQL Server : change NULL to blank on select statement for all columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I am calling a SQL Server database through my Web API which is then sending the data to my webpage only problem is when it does that some of the values are null and it errors.

How would I make it so when I pull the data using SQL that I make it check every column and row for nulls and change them to `''` without writing `ISNULL(a.BuildingNumber, '')` or am I trying to attempt something that isn't possible.

Or is it possible to loop through the `DataTable` that I make when C# gets the data from SQL Server, if so would something like a foreach loop work instead.

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                var dtb = new DataTable();
                var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dtb);
                return Json(dtb);
            }
```

That is what I do after my query to return it.

Comment: What are you using to interface with the database, is it pure ADO.Net or are you using an ORM? What are the nullable data types?

Comment: I believe you would be mapping data from DB to an object which is where you can make this change.

Comment: @Joe_DM ADO.Net and the nullable data types are all strings but my web page can't use the nulls.

Comment: @Praveen How would I go about doing that as I am fairly new to C#

Comment: Also, what are you returning? E.g. Are you manually reading and parsing values out of a datareader

Comment: If it's all strings, you can safe cast. E.g. Datareader[0] as string

Comment: @Joe_DM could you make an example in an answer so that I can see if its what i'm looking for

Comment: Just read that null is no good. You can use 'reader[0] as string ?? String.Empty'... I'm happy for someone else to post answer with explanation. I'm on phone and fighting autocorrect

Comment: @Joe_DM OK no worries damn auto correct

Comment: Alternatively, maybe check out dapper. Might be exactly what you want. https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

Comment: Instead of using `Json()` you can write your own subclass of `JsonResult` that converts nulls to empty strings using a custom serializer/resolver and return that (`return new MyJson(dtb)`) . See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23832417/491907 for how you might implement the null to empty. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20981338/491907 for how to implement a subclass of JsonResult (though this answer is about excluding nulls, you can combine the two approaches). The plus side to this is then you have something reusable and you don't have to do it in SQL.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I think the main problem is that the type is DbNull which is different to null

Comment: Same concept applies, check for DBNull.Value instead

Comment: I just need to be able to turn any of the columns if they are null to ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the desired result by doing it in my javascript like so

```
getData() {
    var search_url = "http://10.0.1.96/testwebapi/api/case/"
        + this.state.ApiUrl + "/" + this.props.match.params.id

    var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest =
        axios
            .get(search_url)
            .then(function (result) {
                for (var property in result.data[0]) {
                    if (result.data[0][property] === null) {
                        result.data[0][property] = '';
                    }
                }    
                _this.setState({
                    [_this.state.ApiUrl]: result.data[0]
                }, function () {
                });

            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check in the following way

```
string ServiceName = reader["ColumnNameFromQuery"] != System.DBNull.Value ? reader["ColumnNameFromQuery"].ToString() : "";
```

An Example

```
                string QueryGetData = "select Name as Name , Age as Age from tableone;";

                        SqlCommand cmd = m_SqlConnection.CreateCommand();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = QueryGetData;
                        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            List<string> Data = new List<string>();

                            string strName = reader["Name"] != System.DBNull.Value ? reader["ServiceName"].ToString() : "";
            string strName = reader["Age"] != System.DBNull.Value ? reader["Age"].ToString() : "";

           //If Int Set Default as Zero
            int nIntValue = reader["IntColumnName"] != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(reader["IntColumnName"].ToString()) : 0;

            }
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to do that for each column though?

Comment: Yes , i'm afraid so.

Comment: do you know how to do datareader?? as im looking at a scalable system that i dont have to edit every part to update 1 thing

Comment: I will add my sample query and how i do that for reference. Use if you find it useful.

Comment: This can be done easier with: 'string ServiceName = reader["ColumnNameFromQuery"] as string ?? string.Empty;' and since all columns are string it can be put in a loop

Comment: for loop would i just do foreach(DataRow row in dtb.Rows){ string ServiceName = reader["ColumnNameFromQuery"] as string ?? string.Empty

Comment: It would be more like 'row as string ?? string.Empty' in that example for each.